# does mov DWORD PTR 32[rsp], 5 means mov DWORD PTR [rsp+32], 5?

Tags: disassembly, windows, functions, stack, x86-64

I am learning about windows x64 calling convention, where the first four arguments are passed to registers and left arguments are passed through the stack. To see it, I checked the assembly of the test file that I made. I understood the passing of first four arguments through the register, the left arguments were passed through the stack but I didn't understood the assembly of the instruction. It looked like this:

```
mov DWORD PTR 40[rsp], 6
mov DWORD PTR 32[rsp], 5
```

I don't know what does 40[rsp] means, maybe rsp+40 .
If anyone knows, please explain to me

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: gcc with tag -S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `mov DWORD PTR 40[rsp], 6` is the same as `mov DWORD PTR [rsp + 40], 6`. The first syntax makes a lot more sense in cases where the constant is the base address of an array, and the register contains a byte offset into that array. That's the use case the syntax was designed for.

Comment: Thanks, now i understood!